# Flashing a shed roof ledger on gable side of house

Tags: roof, flashing, ledger

I'm installing a shed roof on the gable side of my house and I'm wondering about flashing the ledger board. As far as I understand, these are the steps:

1. Remove the vinyl siding above and below the ledger location.
2. Cut the house wrap in the center of the location so it will fold down and up over the siding temporarily.
3. Install ice and weathershield over the sheathing past the sides, top, and bottom of the ledger location.
4. Attach the ledger.
5. Install metal flashing above the ledger leaving room for purlins and corrugated metal roofing. Tape over the nail holes in flashing.
6. Install J channel around the sides and bottom of ledger and on top of the flashing. Then tape over nails of J channel.
7. Reinstall house wrap to cover nails of the j channel and tape it.
8. Reinstall siding.

Am I correct in this process?

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but personally i'd be installing the flashing after the corrugated roof sheeting.  depending on whether the roof is for an indoor space or outdoor I'd be leafing the houre wrap undisturbed.